# Calculating the optimization problem for a SVM in python

Tags: python, svm

I am trying to understand, how SVMs work internally.

Let's say, I have these two vectors $\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
3
\end{pmatrix}$  and $\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}$ and the labels are 1 and -1.

Then the optimization problem would be

Min $\frac{1}{2}\vec{w}^T\vec{w}$

with $g_1 = 1 * (\vec{w} \begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
3
\end{pmatrix}+b) - 1\geq 0$

and $g_1 = -1 * (\vec{w} \begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}+b) - 1\geq 0$

Right?

So, where do I go from here?

I saw code that initialitzes $\vec{w}$ to some value and then does gradient descent on it and for each value of it just checks if the contraints are correct for each data point.

Is this a valid way to do this?

If not, how I implement this in code in a simple way?

Comment: Welcome to the site, SVM uses quadratic programming with Linear constraints. There are many ways in which one can solve this problem try searching “quadratic programming” “active set” if you are really interested in optimization then I would recommend Numerical Optimization book by Nocedal and Wright which has several algorithm to solve the optimization problem that you state in the question

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I am really just looking for a simple solution and I cant tell you how many videos Ive seen and blogs Ive read in the past days, so please understand that another book recommendation just wont help me. I dont want to dive into the depths of numerical optimization, Lagrange for me is already like rocket science, I am simply looking for a very easy way to solve this and possibly code it myself.

Comment: If many blog posts and many videos haven't moved you closer to understanding how to solve this problem, then an authoritative resource like a textbook seems like a good place to search next. Nocedal and Wright's book is a highly regarded numerical optimization text. Blog posts and videos are usually much lower-quality because they abuse notation and skip over key concepts.

Comment: Okay, I'll give it a look. Maybe you could answer this: am I right in saying, that w and b have to be initialized with some values to get the optimization process started?

Comment: What is b, is it a vector [1 -1]